# Operand type clash: int is incompatible with uniqueidentifier

Tags: c#, sql-server-2005

I am getting an SQLException "Operand type clash: int is incompatible with uniqueidentifier"
when I am trying to execute the below stored procedure from C# code.

```
create proc sp_Get_Allfields_Account_Public
@username varchar(20),
@password varchar(20),
@acc_num UniqueIdentifier out,
@cust_name varchar(20) out,
@balance float out
as
select @acc_num=acc_num,@cust_name=cust_name,@balance=balance from Account_Public where username=@username and password=@password
```

C# code is as follows

```
cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_Get_Allfields_Account_Public", con);
               cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

               // Add Input Parameters
               cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", username);
               cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", password);   

               // Add output parameters
               cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@acc_num", SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier);
               cmd.Parameters["@acc_num"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

               cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cust_name", SqlDbType.VarChar);
               cmd.Parameters["@cust_name"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

               cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@balance", SqlDbType.Float);
               cmd.Parameters["@balance"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

               cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Table definition

```
create table Account_Public
(
acc_num uniqueidentifier,
cust_name varchar(20),
username varchar(20),
password varchar(20),
balance float
)
```

Comment: Is the error on the ExecuteNonQuery or one of the AddWithValue?

Comment: The exception is on ExecuteNonQuery

Comment: As an aside, never prefix your stored procedure names with `sp_` - these should be reserved for system procedures. See http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DBProgramming/MSSQLServer/don-t-start-your-procedures-with-sp_

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's because you're calling `AddWithValue`, then passing the value as the enum (which is interpreted as an `int`).

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@acc_num", SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier);
```

Use a different method (probably just `Add`).

Comment: I think this is it. Just spotted the WithValue part.

Comment: Tried Add method but this time I get the exception
String[3]: the Size property has an invalid size of 0.

Comment: @Nadeem You need to specify a size for your varchar output variable, otherwise it defaults to 0, and you can't have an nvarchar(0).

Answer (score 0):

This may seem a bit redundant, but are you sure that the data type of column `[Account_Public].[acc_num]` is actually `uniqueidentifier` and not `int`?

Try this instead:

```
cmd = new SqlCommand("select @acc_num=acc_num,@cust_name=cust_name,@balance=balance from Account_Public where username=@username and password=@password", con);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
```

with the same parameters. Do you get the same error?

Also, I *strongly* recommend that you specify explicit sizes on all the char parameters. It's not so important for the input parameters, but it's very important for the output ones.